# Running background in P5

Tags: p5.js

Im trying to make a side-scroller game and I got stuck on the running background part. I've looked for solutions and I've discovered some , but they were using javascript not the p5 library.
I started from the tutorials found on [The Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/user/shiffman) , and looked over all the examples and references on their site.

Although I could avoid this by using something else, just for the sake of it being here in case someone gets stuck on the same issue, could anyone offer a solution to this **in p5**? Disclaimer: Im a total noob p5.js.

later edit : By running background i mean moving Background image in a loop from left to right

Comment: What's your question? What exactly do you mean by "the running background part"? Can you please post a [mcve] and a specific technical question?

Comment: I've added a later edit. Sorry for the misunderstanding and lack of specification

Comment: And what have you tried so far? It sounds like you know what you need to do. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I don't know if its the right way to go, I've created an object the size of the canvas. and attached an image to it . Im moving it in the draw function one pixel at a time. The object has an update and a display function (both called in the draw function ) Using a second object to fill the remaining screen ( to the right ) is the only wait i can give the impression of what im trying to do . 
it is not ideal, and its not using the background function, therefore is not efficient. Was hoping for a better solution.

Comment: Why is it not ideal? Why would using the `background()` function be more efficient? What efficiency are you measuring? What would make a solution "better" than what you already have?

Comment: Because Im loading the image twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155274/discussion-between-mihai-labo-and-kevin-workman).

Comment: Why would you load the image twice? Just load it once and draw it twice. This is why we ask for a [mcve]. It's impossible to help you without seeing any code.

Comment: Just arrived at home. Will provide code tomorrow. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, from the discussion we had in the comments, it sounds like you're overthinking it.

The [general approach to animation](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation) (that tutorial is for Processing, but the principles apply to P5.js as well) is as follows:

- **Step 1:** Create a set of variables that represent the **state** of your scene.
- **Step 2:** Use those variables to draw your scene every frame.
- **Step 3:** Change those variables over time to make your scene move.

You already know what to do: load an image that contains your background, then draw that image, and move it a little bit each frame.

You've said you want to call the `background()` function instead of the `image()` function, which doesn't make a ton of sense. The `background()` function is not any more efficient than the `image()` function. In fact, the `background()` function just calls the `image()` function for you!

From [the P5.js source](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js):

```
p5.prototype.background = function() {
  if (arguments[0] instanceof p5.Image) {
    this.image(arguments[0], 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  } else {
    this._renderer.background.apply(this._renderer, arguments);
  }
  return this;
};
```

P5.js simply checks whether the argument is an image, and if so, calls the `image()` function for you. So it doesn't really make sense to say that using the `image()` function is "less efficient" than using the `background()` function.

Taking a step back, you should really avoid thinking about these kinds of micro-optimizations until you **A:** understand the problem and **B:** actually have a problem. Don't make assumptions about "efficiency" until you've actually measured your code for performance.

Anyway, back to your question. You also said that you're loading the image twice, which you shouldn't have to do. You can just load the image once (make sure you do that in the `setup()` function and not the `draw()` function, and then draw that image twice:

```
var img;
function preload() {
  img = loadImage("image.jpg");
}
function setup() {
  image(img, 0, 0);
  image(img, 100, 100);
}
```

And since you can draw two images, you'd then just draw them next to each other. Here's an example using colored rectangles to show the approach more clearly:

```js
var offsetX = 0;

function setup() { 
  createCanvas(200, 200);
} 

function draw() { 
  background(0);
 
  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(offsetX, 0, width, height);
 
  fill(0, 0, 255);
  rect(offsetX + width, 0, width, height);
 
  offsetX--;
  if(offsetX <= -width){
  offsetX = 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
```

There are other ways to do it, like creating an image that contains the wrapping itself. But the general approach is pretty much the same.

If you're still stuck, please try to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) like I've done here. For example, notice that I created a simple sketch that deals with images, and another simple sketch that deals with moving rectangles. Then if you get stuck, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your answer. IT was exactly what i was looking for. Will add my code in another comment, but this will remain the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a late answer.. but you can make the environment 3D and then move the camera.

Docs: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/camera

Example:

```
function setup() {
   createCanvas(windowWidth - 200, windowHeight - 200, WEBGL);
   background(175);
   frameRate(30);
}

function draw() {
   background(175);

   //move the camera Xaxis when mouse is moved
   let camX = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0,width);
   camera(camX, 0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), camX, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

   normalMaterial();
   noStroke();
   ambientLight(251,45,43);
   box(100, 100, 50);
   ang += 0.3;
   rotateY(ang * 0.03);
}
```

Keep calm and Happy Coding!